# Implement a fast optimization algorithm using fixed point method in matlab

Tags: algorithm, matlab, image-processing, optimization

I am implementing a fast optimization algorithm using fixed point method in matlab. The goal of that method is that find optimal value of `u`. Denote `u={u_i,i=1..2}`. The optimal value of u can be obtained as following steps:

[image]

Sorry about my image because I cannot type mathematics equation in here.
To do that task, I tried to find u follows above steps. However, I don't know how to implement the term \sum_{j!=i} (u_j-1) in equation 25. This is my code. Please see it and could you give me some comment or suggestion about my implementation to correct them. Currently, I tried to run that code but it give an incorrect answer.

```
function u = compute_u_TV(Im0, N_class)
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Initialization
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
theta=0.001;
gamma=0.01;
tau=0.1;
sigma=0.1;
N_class=2; % only have u1 and u2
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Iterative segmentation process
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
for i=1:N_class
    v(:,:,i) = Im0/max(Im0(:)); % u between 0 and 1.   
    qxv(:,:,i) = zeros(size(Im0));
    qyv(:,:,i) = zeros(size(Im0));
    u(:,:,i) = v(:,:,i);
for iteration=1:10000
    u_temp=u;
    % Update v
    Divqi = ( BackwardX(qxv(:,:,i)) + BackwardY(qyv(:,:,i)) );
    Term = Divqi - u(:,:,i)/ (theta*gamma);
    TermX = ForwardX(Term);
    TermY = ForwardY(Term); 
    Norm = sqrt(TermX.^2 + TermY.^2);
    Denom = 1 + tau*Norm;
    %Equation 24
    qxv(:,:,i) = (qxv(:,:,i) + tau*TermX)./Denom;
    qyv(:,:,i) = (qyv(:,:,i) + tau*TermY)./Denom;  
    v(:,:,i) = u(:,:,i) - theta*gamma* Divqi;  %Equation 23   
    % Update u  
    u(:,:,i) = (v(:,:,i) - theta* gamma* Divqi -theta*gamma*sigma*(sum(u(:))-u(:,:,i)-1))./(1+theta* gamma*sigma);
    u(:,:,i) = max(u(:,:,i),0); 
    u(:,:,i) = min(u(:,:,i),1);
    check=u_temp(:,:,i)-u(:,:,i);
    if(abs(sum(check(:)))<=0.1)
        break;  
    end
end
end

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Sub-functions- X.Berson
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
function [dx]=BackwardX(u);
[Ny,Nx] = size(u);
dx = u;
dx(2:Ny-1,2:Nx-1)=( u(2:Ny-1,2:Nx-1) - u(2:Ny-1,1:Nx-2) );
dx(:,Nx) = -u(:,Nx-1);

function [dy]=BackwardY(u);
[Ny,Nx] = size(u);
dy = u;
dy(2:Ny-1,2:Nx-1)=( u(2:Ny-1,2:Nx-1) - u(1:Ny-2,2:Nx-1) );
dy(Ny,:) = -u(Ny-1,:);

function [dx]=ForwardX(u);
[Ny,Nx] = size(u);
dx = zeros(Ny,Nx);
dx(1:Ny-1,1:Nx-1)=( u(1:Ny-1,2:Nx) - u(1:Ny-1,1:Nx-1) );

function [dy]=ForwardY(u);
[Ny,Nx] = size(u);
dy = zeros(Ny,Nx);
dy(1:Ny-1,1:Nx-1)=( u(2:Ny,1:Nx-1) - u(1:Ny-1,1:Nx-1) );

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% End of sub-function
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Comment: In equation (25), does `\sum_{j!=i}u_j-1` is `\sum_{j!=i} (u_j-1)` or `(\sum_{j!=i} u_j)-1`? Since `\sum(u_j)=1`, first one is equivalent to `-u_j-(N-1)`, and second one is `-u_j`. Or do I miss something?

Comment: @Bentoy13: As the paper, the author wrote that (\sum_{j!=i} u_j-1). I think that the condition is that u_1+u_2+..u_n=1. Hence u_i=1-sum_{i!=j}(u_j)

Comment: Thank you to precise that point. And sorry for my typo, I invert `j` and `i` in my comment (bad paste). My point was more about simplifying the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do

```
u(:,:,i) = (v(:,:,i) - theta* gamma* Divqi -theta*gamma*sigma* ...
           (sum(u(:,:,1:size(u,3) ~= i),3) -1))./(1+theta* gamma*sigma);
```

The part you were searching for is

```
sum(u(:,:,1:size(u,3) ~= i),3)
```

Let's decompose this :

```
 1:size(u,3) ~= i
```

is a vector containing all values from 1 to the max size of `u` on the third dimension except `i`.

Then

```
u(:,:,1:size(u,3) ~= i)
```

is all the matrix of the third dimension of `u` except for `j = i`

Finally,

```
sum(...,3)
```

is the sum of all the matrix by the thrid dimension.

Let me know if it does help!

Comment: It is very good suggestion. However, I did not give one condition for you that is \sum of u_i=1. For that condition, I think that above equation looks like that minus 1 must be outside of sum. Hence I think the correct must be sum(u(:,:,1:size(u,3) ~= i),3)-1. Do you think that?

Comment: As Bentoy said in the comments, if the `-1` is outside of the sum, then the sum - 1 equals u_i, so I'm not sure it does make sense!

Comment: Let check my answer in the Bentoy13

Comment: Well according to the way it's written, the minus should be outside, so I guess it must be right. Can you confirm it so I can edit my answer!

Comment: Yes. i read one more paper about that problem. The minus one must outside because it use  Euler-Lagrange to find it. Let see page 5 in the short paper at https://www.dropbox.com/s/gtjas7dwakompee/05459239.pdf?dl=0

Comment: Did my editing! Is there any other thing about my answer that's not ok?

Comment: Do you check my condition to stop |u_i(n+1)-u_i(n)|<epsilon. Is it correct?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82504/discussion-between-hamtarowarrior-and-user8264).